# Argument in Dockerfile not passed as executed command

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I'm trying to download the latest WordPress version without any content inside it, but I'm having trouble automating the latest version number so that I don't have to manually change it when the new version of WordPress comes out.

In my Dockerfile I have

```
ARG LATESTWPVER="$(curl -s https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.5/ | head -n 4 | tail -n 1)"
ADD $(https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-$LATESTWPVER-no-content.zip) /var/www/latest.zip
```

But the problem is that my `LATESTWPVER` is not `4.9.8`, and I get the error

> ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder962069305/$(https:/downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-$(curl -s https:/api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.5/ | head -n 4 | tail -n 1)-no-content.zip): no such file or directory

It passes the entire command and I'd like to have the output of that command.

In my shell file the

```
#!/bin/bash

WP_LATEST="$(curl -s https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.5/ | head -n 4 | tail -n 1)"
echo $WP_LATEST
```

will return the number `4.9.8`.

From the error, I'm guessing that you can only assign something to the variable, but not execute it. Is there a way to execute a command and assign it to a variable and pass it as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dockerfile is not a shell or a build script, so it will not execute what you pass in ARG. There is a workaround - define the version as an `ARG` and pass that during build.

Dockerfile:

--

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG LATESTWPVER
RUN echo $LATESTWPVER
ADD https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-$LATESTWPVER-no-content.zip /var/www/latest.zip
```

---

```
docker build --build-arg LATESTWPVER=`curl -s https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.5/ | head -n 4 | tail -n 1` .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.656kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 113a43faa138
Step 2/4 : ARG LATESTWPVER
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 64f47dcfe7fa
Step 3/4 : RUN echo $LATESTWPVER
 ---> Running in eb5fdd005d77
4.9.8
Removing intermediate container eb5fdd005d77
 ---> 1015629b927e
Step 4/4 : ADD https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-$LATESTWPVER-no-content.zip /var/www/latest.zip
Downloading [==================================================>]  7.118MB/7.118MB

 ---> 72f0d3790e51
Successfully built 72f0d3790e51
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought, and after a talk with my devops he suggested the same. Thanks!